# How to close CRM opportunity entity using C# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am new to CRM. I had implemented OAuth for application. I am using web api approach to access specific CRM user data. I had implemented web api successfully for "Get User Opportunities", "Update User Opportunity". But i am unable to do same for "close opportunity" or "win opportunity".

Note: I am not using OrganizationService proxy while accessing user data. I am using OAuth token and  calling specific API request URL.

Please guide me to achieve same. Highly appreciable if anyone can show any samples on code and or how to test same in postman.

My queries:

1) Is it possible using OAuth token,can we connect to OrganizationServiceProxy without passing user credentials?

Ex: Get Opportunities

Request URL : https://testdevcrm.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/opportunities

Header:

Authorization:Bearer (accessToken)

Accept:application/json

OData-MaxVersion:4.0

OData-Version:4.0

Method Type : GET

**Code**

```
  #region FectchUserOpportunities
    public async Task<JToken> FectchUserOpportunities(string systemuserid,string bearerToken)
    {
        JToken jResu = null;
        try
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            string filter = "&$filter=_createdby_value eq '" + systemuserid + "' and opportunityid ne null and statuscode eq 1&$orderby=createdon asc&$top=5";
            string opportunitiesURL = string.Concat(GenericMethods.GetAppSetting("FetchCRMOpportunitiesAPI"), filter);
            var result = httpClient.GetAsync(opportunitiesURL).Result;

            if (result != null)
            {
                var opporJSON = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JToken jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(opporJSON);
                jResu = jsonResult["value"];
            }
            else
            {
                jResu = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return jResu;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the MS SDK?

Comment: @AnkyUser, I posted answer which is working perfectly for me.

Comment: @daryl, do you mean nuget package for CRM?

Comment: Yes.  If you're using the .Net Framework, then why they heck wouldn't you use it?

Comment: I have authentication in my application, I need to get CRM data depend on user logged in. with the help of MS SDK, i can only pass client credentials in OrganizationProxy. If you know how we can pass auth token (Bearer token) to Organization proxy, please provide code for same.

Answer (score 1):

Well There is an Specific Action which can be called from WebAPI to Close opportunity as WIN or LOSS. It's called

> WinOpportunity
>
> LoseOpportunity

Now how do you call it via Webapi. Here is the sample Code From front end Side to call it. You can easily replicate this using Postman and see how this helps.

```
var parameters = {};
var opportunityclose = {};
opportunityclose.activityid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; //Delete if creating new record 
opportunityclose["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.opportunityclose";
opportunityclose["opportunityid@odata.bind"] = "/opportunities(8CA20837-715F-E911-A83A-000D3A3852A3)";
parameters.OpportunityClose = opportunityclose;
parameters.Status = 0;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/WinOpportunity", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

---

```
var parameters = {};
var opportunityclose = {};
opportunityclose.activityid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; //Delete if creating new record 
opportunityclose["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.opportunityclose";
opportunityclose["opportunityid@odata.bind"] = "/opportunities(8CA20837-715F-E911-A83A-000D3A3852A3)";
parameters.OpportunityClose = opportunityclose;
parameters.Status = 0;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/LoseOpportunity", false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 204) {
                //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented C# code using web api for opportunity as WON.

**Code:**

```
    #region UpdateUserOpportunityWon

    public async Task<string> UpdateUserOpportunityWon(string bearerToken, string opportunityid, string wonsubject, string actualend = "", int actualrevenue = 0, string wondesc = "")
    {
        string jResu = "";
        try
        {
            string opportunitiesURL = string.Format(GenericMethods.GetAppSetting("UpdateCRMOpportunityAPI"), opportunityid);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            string jsonBody = "";
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actualend))
            {
                jsonBody = "{'Status':3,'OpportunityClose':{'subject':'" + wonsubject + "','actualrevenue':" + actualrevenue + ",'description':'" + wondesc + "','opportunityid@odata.bind':'" + opportunitiesURL + "'}}";
            }
            else
            {
                jsonBody = "{'Status':3,'OpportunityClose':{'subject':'" + wonsubject + "','actualrevenue':" + actualrevenue + ",'actualend':'" + actualend + "','description':'" + wondesc + "','opportunityid@odata.bind':'" + opportunitiesURL + "'}}";
            }
            var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            string opportunitiesWonURL = string.Format(GenericMethods.GetAppSetting("UpdateOpportunityWon"), opportunityid);

            var result = httpClient.PostAsync(opportunitiesWonURL, content).Result;
          //  TelemetryHelper.Trace("API res", result.ToString());
            string statuscode = result.StatusCode.ToString();
            if (result != null)
            {
                var opporJSON = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (statuscode.ToLower() == "nocontent")
                {
                    jResu = statuscode; //success
                }
                else
                {
                    JToken jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(opporJSON);
                    if (jsonResult["error"] != null)
                    {
                        jResu = jsonResult["error"]["message"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                jResu = Resources.CommonAPIError + statuscode;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TelemetryHelper.Trace("API Ex", ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return jResu;
    }

    #endregion
```